# Laravel: how to sort by related model with pagination & filter

Tags: javascript, laravel, sorting

It's been three days that I block on my configuration. I can not sort by model reported, I tried many methods but nothing conclusive, for example, sortBy / sortByDesc, join table but no solution

I want to perform paging, sorting, and server-side filters. Filters can be multiple. Everything works except sort by the related model
I get the URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/list?page=1&limit=30&sort=user__created_at&direction=desc&search__user__name=James&search__group__name=Client`

the query `search__model__col` allows me to chain several searches on several models or columns

Here is my code :

```
    public static function pagination(Request $request, $model, $relation, $modelStringify)
    {
        $modelSortBy = explode('__', $request->query('sort'))[0]; // user
        $tableSortBy = explode('__', $request->query('sort'))[1]; // created_at
        $query       = $request->query(); // ['page' => 1, 'limit' => 30...]
        $direction   = $request->query('direction'); // desc
        try {

            $model = $model->with($relation);

            //TODO : orderBy relationship
            if ($modelSortBy === $modelStringify): // modelStringify = 'user'
                $model->orderBy($tableSortBy, $direction);
            else:
                 // sort server side here 
            endif;

            foreach (array_keys($query) as $q) {
                if (strpos($q, 'search__') === 0) {
                    $modelSearchBy = explode('__', $q)[1]; // ['user', 'group']
                    $tableSearchBy = explode('__', $q)[2]; // ['name', 'name']
                    $valueSearchBy = $query[$q];
                    if ($modelSearchBy === $modelStringify):
                        $model->where($tableSearchBy, 'like', $valueSearchBy . '%');
                    else:
                        $model->whereHas($modelSearchBy, function (Builder $q) use ($valueSearchBy, $tableSearchBy) {
                            $q->where($tableSearchBy, 'like', $valueSearchBy . '%'); // $valueSearchBy = ['James', 'Client']
                        });
                    endif;
                }
            }
            return $model;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $e], 400);
        }
    }
```

Here is an example for `user` `belongsTo` `group` :

```
return response()->json([
    'items' => Utils::pagination($request, new User(), [
        'group',
    ], 'user')->paginate($limit)->toArray()
]);
```

How can I introduce the sort by the related model in this configuration?

For example, for sorted by group name, I get the URL `&sort=group__name`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this can easily done in Laravel. Someone suggested a syntax to do this in Laravel [here](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/592), but Taylor closed the issue.

On all the other resources I could find people [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123568/laravel-sort-relationship) [using](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eloquent-order-by-related-table) [joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261546/order-by-relationship-column), but that wouldn't easily fit with your more generic approach.

Laravel also recently introduced "subquery enhancements" that include sorting by a subquery value (search for "Eloquent Subquery Enhancements" on [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/releases)), but I couldn't figure out how to use it to make ordering by an Eloquent relationship value easier.

I think your best bet would be to use a third-party package such as the one that is linked to from the Github issue, [fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join](https://packagist.org/packages/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join). After installing it, you can simply create a new base model class that uses the `use Fico7489\Laravel\EloquentJoin\Traits\EloquentJoin;` trait and then inherit that class from your models.

```
use Fico7489\Laravel\EloquentJoin\Traits\EloquentJoin;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
    use EloquentJoin;
```

```
class ExampleModel extends BaseModel
```

Then you will be able to sort by a relationship using the [`orderByJoin`](https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join#new-clauses-for-eloquent-builder-on-belongsto-and-hasone-relations-) function:

```
$model->orderByJoin('<relationship>.<column>', $direction);
```

The `relationship` value above would be the name of a relationship that you have defined on a model.

Keep in mind the the `orderByJoin` function only supports `BelongsTo` and `HasOne` relationships.

Something else to keep in mind is that neither Laravel nor the laravel-eloquent-join package protects your from SQL injection in column names (or in the direction value in the `orderByJoin` function). The Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#introduction) recommend that you use a whitelist for column names:

> PDO does not support binding column names. Therefore, you should never allow user input to dictate the column names referenced by your queries, including "order by" columns, etc. If you must allow the user to select certain columns to query against, always validate the column names against a white-list of allowed columns.