# Laravel Eloquent, orderBy with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I have an `Project` table which belongsTo a `Client` what I want to achieve is ordering the `Project` table by Clients name, how do I call the name of the client to the `orderBy` of the `Project` query?

```
        $projects = Project::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
        ->search(trim($this->search))
        ->orderBy($this->column, $this->order)
        ->paginate($this->size);
```

Comment: Take a look at the upvoted (not accepted) answer here: [How to order by another table join by eager loading in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215967/how-to-order-by-another-table-join-by-eager-loading-in-laravel) Seems like you would need to join and simply reference that table.column on the orderBy.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a subquery:

```php
$projects = Project::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
    ->search(trim($this->search))
    ->orderBy(
        Client::select('name')
            ->whereColumn('id', 'projects.client_id')
            ->limit(1)
    )
    ->paginate($this->size);
```

If you also need the `orderBy` field to be conditional, you can wrap it in a `when()`.

You can read more about Eloquent subqueries here: https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements